# Get choices from select in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm new in Symfony2 and Twig, really I only markup the views of some forms. I have created a generic forms.twig.html with some macros for render type of input. 
Then I pass to the select type the options list for selects options, but I cant get this options in the vars array from symfony2. ¿Is this possible?

Macro

```
{% macro select(name, options, selected) %}
<div class="innerB">
<select class="form-control" name="{{name}}">
{% for option in options %}
  {% if option.value == selected %}
    <option value="{{option.value}}" selected>{{ option.value }}</option>
  {% else %}
    <option value="{{option.value}}">{{ option.value }}</option>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

And this is the twig:

```
<!-- Print selects -->
{% if type == 'choice' %}
{{ macroforms.label(item.vars.name, item.vars.label) }}
{{ macroforms.select(item.vars.name, item.vars.choices, item.vars.selected?) }}
{% endif %}
```

Updated: This works... The problem was type of element, "choice" and not "collection", but now, I want to access each element for the collection, which are choices... Any idea?

Comment: You can beter create a custom form theme if you want to style a form: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Thanks for responding, but, do you know if it's possible to get the select options?